# I'd want to, not common or wrong?

Tags: grammar

I feel like I've heard "I'd want to" in very few cases or maybe even not at all. Is this an old settled down preference by the natives or there's a grammatical point that supports it? For example, Is this sentence grammatically all right?

> "If there is one thing that I'd want to say about my brother, it's
>   that he's very stubborn."

Comment: I'd want to know more about why you think this might be wrong before I tried to compose an answer.

Comment: @J.R. This is not as simple as it seems, as I'd could be **I would** or **I had**. M-J, in this case it's **I would**: does that make sense to you?

Comment: Whether would or had has been contracted can be determined from context, since they take different tense verbs. "I'd gone" cannot be would; "I'd want" cannot be had.

Comment: Guys sorry I didn't mention, yes it's "would". As I've said, I thought it might be wrong because I hardly could remember encountering it. So do you think my example sentence in yellow is okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I'd want to"* is short for *"I would want to"* and is common usage for most Americans. Perhaps your area doesn't use that particular contraction often and is why you think it is not common.

And yes, your example sentence

> "If there is one thing that **I'd want** to say about my brother, it's that he's very stubborn."

is grammatically correct. Your sentence is saying

> "If there is one thing that **I would want** to say about my brother, it's that he's very stubborn.